# Do these two PHP OOP syntaxes yield the same result?

Tags: php, oop, function, object

In PHP, is:

```
$objectVar = someClassName::someFunction($var);
```

the same as:

```
$object = new someClassName();
$objectVar = $object->someFunction($var);
```

Comment: No, but if you changed it to $object::someFunction($var), then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

```
$objectVar = someClassName::someFunction($var);
```

Here, `someFunction` is a static method; i.e. it belongs to a class, not an object.

```
$object    = new someClassName();
$objectVar = $object->someFunction($var);
```

In this code, it is an instance method that should be accessed through an object.

The result could be the same, but the handle used to call the method is different.

Comment: To clarify, a method can be declared static/public/protected in its definition, right?  So the real difference is in whether it "belongs" to only a class as compared to belonging to an instance of an object - which you term an "instance method" ? I can only foresee that result changing via a change in a variable instance, like: $this->varName = value; and then running the instance method.  Does that make logical sense?

Comment: @Ricalsin: Yes. There's also a semantic element here. Is the function a property of each object, or of the type in general? This decision will define whether you make it a static or non-static member function; and _that_ will define which syntax you have to use to call it.